# При выводе sql таблицы d csv,у меня выходят непонятные символы

Tags: python, sql, csv

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['unload_users'])
async def consal(message: types.Message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('reg.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    q = cursor.execute("""SELECT user_id,names,phone,email FROM reg_people""").fetchall()
    file_name = 'users.csv'
    pd.DataFrame(q).to_csv(file_name)
    document = open(file_name, 'rb')

    await message.answer_document(document)
    document.close()
    os.remove(file_name)
```

Comment: Только русские слова превращает в символы

Comment: В принципе не обязательно сохранять в файл, можно создать объект `file = io.BytesIO`, передать его вместо пути в to_csv (кодировку также нужно указать), потом сделать `document = file.getvalue()`

Answer (score -1):

Просто надо в to_csv,поставить кодировку

Comment: Если проблема вызвана банальной ошибкой или опечаткой, то такой вопрос надо закрывать. и уж тем более не стоит давать такие "ответы".